# The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous' on one computer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service(selfhosted) and client, the client uses client certificate and the service uses a service certificate over HTTPS. This works fine on computer but the other throws this :

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Myapp.Client.Main.ServiceManagement.ServiceAgents.General.<GetUserConfigurations>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Project\Myapp\Produkter\MyappUtveckling\Solution\Myapp.Client.Main\Classes\Service Management\Service Agents\General.cs:line 172
```

In the WCF log I can see this :

> Configuration evaluation context not found.

---

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-SE/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUnexpectedResponse.aspx
>   Received bad HTTP response
>   Myapp.vshost.exe 
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException,
>   System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 The HTTP
>   request was forbidden with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'.  at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.TraceResponseException(Exception
>   exception) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException,
>   HttpChannelFactory`1 factory) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory,
>   WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.ProcessResponse(HttpWebResponse
>   response, WebException responseException) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.OnGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult
>   result) at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken) at
>   System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken) at
>   System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result,
>   IntPtr userToken) at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.ProcessResponse() at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponse(CoreResponseData
>   coreResponseData) at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetAndOrProcessResponse(Object
>   responseOrException) at
>   System.Net.ConnectionReturnResult.SetResponses(ConnectionReturnResult
>   returnResult) at System.Net.Connection.ReadComplete(Int32 bytesRead,
>   WebExceptionStatus errorStatus) at
>   System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.Net.Connection.ReadCallbackWrapper(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken) at
>   System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result,
>   IntPtr userToken) at
>   System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessFrameBody(Int32 readBytes,
>   Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest
>   asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security._SslStream.ReadFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest
>   asyncRequest) at System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest.CompleteRequest(Int32
>   result) at
>   System.Net.FixedSizeReader.CheckCompletionBeforeNextRead(Int32 bytes)
>   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult
>   transportResult) at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr
>   userToken) at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object
>   state) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken) at
>   System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result,
>   IntPtr userToken) at
>   System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped) at
>   System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP) </StackTrace>
>   <ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException:
>   The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. ---&gt; System.Net.WebException: The remote server
>   returned an error: (403) Forbidden.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result)    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---  System.Net.WebException, System, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   The remote server returned an error: (403)
>   Forbidden.  at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result) </StackTrace> <ExceptionString>System.Net.WebException: The
>   remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result)

---

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-SE/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx
>   Throwing an exception.
>   Myapp.vshost.exe 
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException,
>   System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 The HTTP
>   request was forbidden with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'.  at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException,
>   HttpChannelFactory`1 factory) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory,
>   WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.ProcessResponse(HttpWebResponse
>   response, WebException responseException) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.OnGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult
>   result) at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken) at
>   System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken) at
>   System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result,
>   IntPtr userToken) at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.ProcessResponse() at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponse(CoreResponseData
>   coreResponseData) at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetAndOrProcessResponse(Object
>   responseOrException) at
>   System.Net.ConnectionReturnResult.SetResponses(ConnectionReturnResult
>   returnResult) at System.Net.Connection.ReadComplete(Int32 bytesRead,
>   WebExceptionStatus errorStatus) at
>   System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.Net.Connection.ReadCallbackWrapper(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken) at
>   System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result,
>   IntPtr userToken) at
>   System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessFrameBody(Int32 readBytes,
>   Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest
>   asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security._SslStream.ReadFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest
>   asyncRequest) at System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest.CompleteRequest(Int32
>   result) at
>   System.Net.FixedSizeReader.CheckCompletionBeforeNextRead(Int32 bytes)
>   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult
>   transportResult) at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr
>   userToken) at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object
>   state) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken) at
>   System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result,
>   IntPtr userToken) at
>   System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped) at
>   System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP) </StackTrace>
>   <ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException:
>   The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. ---&gt; System.Net.WebException: The remote server
>   returned an error: (403) Forbidden.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result)    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---  System.Net.WebException, System, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   The remote server returned an error: (403)
>   Forbidden.  at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result) </StackTrace> <ExceptionString>System.Net.WebException: The
>   remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result)

My first thougt was certificates but both computers matches.

Im creating the channel on the client like this :

```
private async Task<ChannelFactory<T>> CreateChannelFactory(LoginTypeBase loginType, MyappToken token)
        {
            var service = await _ConsulService.GetServiceBlocking(loginType.MyappServicesToUse, forceRefresh: true, token: new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Token);

            if (service == null)
                throw new MyappServiceCommunicationException();

            var cert = loginType.ClientCertificate;
            var uri = loginType.GetMyappClientServiceURL(service.Address, service.Port);

            var header = AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader(nameof(MyappToken), nameof(MyappToken), token);
            var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(uri, header);

            ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint = null;
            if (loginType.LoginType == LoginType.SmartCard || loginType.LoginType == LoginType.UsernamePasswordSLL)
            {
                var binding = new NetHttpsBinding("netHttpsBinding");
                binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
                if (loginType.LoginType == LoginType.SmartCard)
                    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
                else
                    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;

                serviceEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(T)), binding, endpointAddress);
            }
            else
            {
                var binding = new NetHttpBinding("netHttpBinding");
                serviceEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(T)), binding, endpointAddress);
            }

            serviceEndpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new ProtoEndpointBehavior());
            serviceEndpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CustomMessageInspectorBehavior());


            var v = new ChannelFactory<T>(serviceEndpoint);
            if (loginType.LoginType == LoginType.SmartCard)
            {
                v.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;
                //v.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, cert.Thumbprint);
            }
            return v;
        }
```

The config contains extensions, behaviours and bindings(netHttpsBinding).

The Service is created from code only, nothing from its config file.

Why does it not work on the other computer?